# Bash Grep between two strings in html file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, html

I used the `curl` command to download an `html` file from [homeoint.org/books/boericmm/d.htm](http://homeoint.org/books/boericmm/d.htm) and saved it into a file.

The relevant part looks like this:

```
      <p><font size="2"><a href="d/dam.htm" target="_top">DAM</a> ------&gt;
      DAMIANA (TURNERA)<br>
      <a href="d/daph.htm" target="_top">DAPH</a> ------&gt; DAPHNE INDICA<br>
      <a href="d/dig.htm" target="_top">DIG</a> ------&gt; DIGITALIS PURPUREA
      (DIGITALIS)<br>
      <a href="d/dios.htm" target="_top">DIOS</a> ------&gt; DIOSCOREA VILLOSA<br>
      <a href="d/diosm.htm" target="_top">DIOSM</a> ------&gt; DIOSMA LINCARIS<br>
      <a href="d/diph.htm" target="_top">DIPH</a> ------&gt; DIPHTHERINUM<br>
      <a target="_top" href="d/dol.htm">DOL</a> ------&gt; DOLICHOS PRURIENS
      (DOLICHOS PURIENS - MUCUNA)<br>
      <a href="d/dor.htm" target="_top">DOR</a> ------&gt; DORYPHORA
      DECEMLINEATA (DORYPHORA)<br>
      <a href="d/dros.htm" target="_top">DROS</a> ------&gt; DROSERA
      ROTUNDIFOLIA (DROSERA)<br>
      <a href="d/dubo-m.htm" target="_top">DUBO-M</a> ------&gt; DUBOISIA
      MYOPOROIDES (DUBOISIA)<br>
      <a href="d/dulc.htm" target="_top">DULC</a> ------&gt; DULCAMARA<br>
      &nbsp;</font></p>
```

I need to grep the value from

```
"&gt;" to "<br>"
```

I need output to be:-

```
 DAMIANA (TURNERA)
 DAPHNE INDICA
 DIGITALIS PURPUREA (DIGITALIS)
 DIOSCOREA VILLOSA
 DIOSMA LINCARIS
 DIPHTHERINUM
 DOLICHOS PRURIENS (DOLICHOS PURIENS - MUCUNA)
 DORYPHORA DECEMLINEATA (DORYPHORA)
 DROSERA ROTUNDIFOLIA (DROSERA)
 DUBOISIA MYOPOROIDES (DUBOISIA)
 DULCAMARA
```

i am trying to use the grep command

```
cat d.htm | grep -o -P '(?<=&gt; ).*(?=<br>)'
```

but my output is not complete.

Comment: i used curl command to download the html file from "http://www.homeoint.org/books/boericmm/d.htm" and saved into file.

Answer (score 2):

Using `lynx` to render the HTML into text, then `sed` to delete everything up to the space after `>` on every line (but print only the lines that were actually affected).

```
$ lynx --dump 'http://homeoint.org/books/boericmm/d.htm' | sed -n 's/.*> //p'
DAMIANA (TURNERA)
DAPHNE INDICA
DIGITALIS PURPUREA (DIGITALIS)
DIOSCOREA VILLOSA
DIOSMA LINCARIS
DIPHTHERINUM
DOLICHOS PRURIENS (DOLICHOS PURIENS - MUCUNA)
DORYPHORA DECEMLINEATA (DORYPHORA)
DROSERA ROTUNDIFOLIA (DROSERA)
DUBOISIA MYOPOROIDES (DUBOISIA)
DULCAMARA
```

If you run into issues with `lynx` inserting line-breaks, then increase the width of the "page" from the default 80 to some higher number with `--width` (see the `lynx` manual).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='&gt;|<br>' '!(NR%2){$1=$1; print}' file
DAMIANA (TURNERA)
DAPHNE INDICA
DIGITALIS PURPUREA (DIGITALIS)
DIOSCOREA VILLOSA
DIOSMA LINCARIS
DIPHTHERINUM
DOLICHOS PRURIENS (DOLICHOS PURIENS - MUCUNA)
DORYPHORA DECEMLINEATA (DORYPHORA)
DROSERA ROTUNDIFOLIA (DROSERA)
DUBOISIA MYOPOROIDES (DUBOISIA)
DULCAMARA
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr` to remove line breaks (`tr -d $'\n'`) and to squeeze repeats of `<space>` (`tr -s ' '`), then you can easily `grep`:

```bsh
curl 'http://www.homeoint.org/books/boericmm/d.htm' \
| tr -d $'\n' \
| tr -s ' ' \
|  grep -Po '&gt; *\K[^<]*'
```

Output:

```
DAMIANA (TURNERA)
DAPHNE INDICA
DIGITALIS PURPUREA (DIGITALIS)
DIOSCOREA VILLOSA
DIOSMA LINCARIS
DIPHTHERINUM
DOLICHOS PRURIENS (DOLICHOS PURIENS - MUCUNA)
DORYPHORA DECEMLINEATA (DORYPHORA)
DROSERA ROTUNDIFOLIA (DROSERA)
DUBOISIA MYOPOROIDES (DUBOISIA)
DULCAMARA
```

(your `grep` would also work, but your `.*`  is greedy, you need `.*?`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python` + `BeautifulSoup` to parse the website.

This is not very beautiful as this website's `html` code is **worst** practice, but it works.

---

Put this in a file `script.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def parse(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items=(re.findall('(?<=&gt; )[^<]*', " ".join(str(soup.find_all("p")[4]).split())))
    for i in items:
        print (i)

parse('http://homeoint.org/books/boericmm/d.htm')
```

To get all pages (what I think you want to do ...), replace the last line with:

```py
import string
for c in list(string.ascii_lowercase):
    parse('http://homeoint.org/books/boericmm/'+c+'.htm')
```

And run `python script.py` or `python3 script.py`

Of course you need to have the dependencies installed (`bs4`, `re`, `requests`).